# How to get the index of a character in a String in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, char

If I have a String an I am looping through that String looking at each character, how do I get the index of that character in that String?

I have seen people use "indexOf()" however when I see them use this it only returns the index of the first occurrence of that character. But what if there are multiple occurrences of that same character? How do I get the index of the character I am currently looking at?

I began using:

```
for(c <- str)
```

to look at each character individually.

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite clear why you need to get the index of the character you are currently iterating over, since because you are iterating, you already know what the index is (all you have to do is to keep count). For example, something like this:

```scala
val str = "Hello World"

for ((c, i) ← str.zipWithIndex) println(s"$c is at $i")
// H is at 0
// e is at 1
// l is at 2
// l is at 3
// o is at 4
//   is at 5
// W is at 6
// o is at 7
// r is at 8
// l is at 9
// d is at 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... there are methods which can get this done for you, but lets say there was no such method... even then you can do this by using entry level programming.

```
val string: String  = "my awesome string"

val char: Char = 'e'
```

Now, the most basic solution,

```
var index = 0
val indexListBuffer: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer()

for (c <- string) {
  if (c == char) {
    indexListBuffer.append(index)
  }
  index = index + 1
}

println(indexListBuffer)
```

Comment: Isn't importing `scala.collection.mutable._` required?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **zipWithIndex()** together with **filter()** to search for an index.

```
val str = "12334563"
str.toList.zipWithIndex.filter((x) => x._1 == '3') 
res9: List[(Char, Int)] = List(('3', 2), ('3', 3), ('3', 7))
```

If required you can also remove the **toList()** call.